# OctoberCMS icons selection in Builder

Tags: octobercms

Is there a way to make a Dropdown field with icons like Builder has it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for someone with the same question, this is simple, here is an example of how to do that:

#### Using YAML

```yaml
fields:
  icon:
    label: Icon
    type: dropdown
    span: left
    options:
        'oc-icon-adjust': ['adjust', 'oc-icon-adjust'],
        'oc-icon-adn': ['adn', 'oc-icon-adn'],
        'oc-icon-align-center': ['align-center', 'oc-icon-align-center'],
        'oc-icon-align-justify': ['align-justify', 'oc-icon-align-justify']
```

#### Using get*FieldName*Options

```php
public function getIconOptions
{
    return [
        'oc-icon-adjust' => ['adjust', 'oc-icon-adjust'],
        'oc-icon-adn' => ['adn', 'oc-icon-adn'],
        'oc-icon-align-center' => ['align-center', 'oc-icon-align-center'],
        'oc-icon-align-justify' => ['align-justify', 'oc-icon-align-justify']
    ];
}
```

**Reference**:
https://github.com/rainlab/builder-plugin/blob/master/classes/IconList.php

#### Example using a custom css

```yaml
fields:
  icon:
    label: Icon
    type: dropdown
    span: left
    commentHtml: true
    comment: '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/themename/assets/css/font-custom.css" media="all"/>'
    options:
      tm-accesories: ['accesories', 'tm tm-accesories']
      tm-smartphone: ['smartphone', 'tm tm-smartphone']
      tm-shopping-bag: ['shopping-bag', 'tm tm-shopping-bag']
      tm-grid: ['grid', 'tm tm-grid']
      tm-best-brands: ['best-brands', 'tm tm-best-brands']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not precise enough. Do you need this list in a back-end form?

If so, you can create a partial in which you will put your custom code to create and fill your dropdown

https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-partial

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin now that adds support of backend form widget with icons list: [plugin page](https://octobercms.com/plugin/ginopane-awesomeiconslist). The form widget it provides is even better than the original form the builder.

[image]